# Trying to interpret the message from maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to compile a project with JDK 11. In order to decipher the message, I want to know
what does the string (default-compile) means in this error message?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project nifi-properties: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project nifi-properties: Compilation failure
```

My pm.xml is here

```
<modules>
    <module>nifi-properties</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>    
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: it means that the maven-compiler-task failed because there was a compilation error in the source.

Comment: Look at the context.  You should have more messages preceeding this one.

Answer (score 0):

So I talked to my colleagues and one thing they noticed and I failed to see was there was no JDK installed in the docker image that I was trying to create as a container of this Maven job. There WAS a JRE available, but no JDK. The clue to this was this part of the error message:

```
openjdk-11-jre-headless/now 11.0.2+9-3 amd64 [installed,local]
```

I should see the JDK in the debug message, a correct debug log would be following

```
openjdk-11-jdk-headless/now 11.0.2+9-3 amd64 [installed,local]
```